# Trying to update to Expo SDK 34. Hitting an error of undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.constants.manifest')

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, updating

I was going through the steps to update expo to the most recent version(34.0.0), but I'm stuck at a point where whenever i try to load my emulator it errors out on me with "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.Constants.manifest')". I've followed along the expo docs and knew going in there might be some issues with updating, but I can't find anything related to this issue specifically.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "storybook": "CONFIG_IS_STORYBOOK=true node startWithEnv.js",
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "expo": "^34.0.4",
    "expo-constants": "~6.0.0",
    "formik": "^1.3.2",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-touchable-scale": "^2.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.1",
    "unstated": "^2.1.1",
    "xml-query": "^1.5.0",
    "xml-reader": "^2.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/react-native": "^4.0.7",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "figlet": "^1.2.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "yargs": "^12.0.2"
  }
}
```

and my app.json looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Project Name",
    "description": "This project is really great.",
    "slug": "ProjectName-ios",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "34.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "version": "0.1.4",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/AppIcon@1x.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "it.project.project",
      "config": {
        "usesNonExemptEncryption": false
      },
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Fill this in"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "it.project.project"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run expo install expo-constants.
Change import  of app source code to

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```